# loading progress/percent of all contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, progress

I have some files such as images,json... I want to load them before running the `main()` function, and show the progress in percents when loading.
This is my code:

```
function main(){...}
function progs(imgUrlArray,jsonUrlArray,otherFilesArray){
 var total = imgUrlArray.length + jsonUrlArray.lenght + otherFilesArray.length;
 var increment =  0;
 var percent = 0;
 //method to load image
 for(var i in imgUrlArray){
  $('<img>').attr({
   src:imgUrlArray[i],
   onload : function(){
    increment++;
    percent = total/increment;
    updateProgress(percent);
   }
  })
 }
 //method to load other file here
}
function updateProgress(percent){
 $('#progressBar').width(percent*100+'%').text(percent*100+'%');
 if(percent>=1){
  $('#progressBar').text('complet').animate({opacity:0,height:0},1000,function(){
   $(this).hide();
   main();//now run the main() function
  });
 }
}
```

I need something like that to load json & **other** files as image method, but effective and work correctly when `main()` is running without showing incomplete images or files.

Comment: Ignoring your syntax errors, what is the current state of this code? Does it work, does it cause errors? Wanting it to "work correct" isn't much to go on here.

Comment: i need to know  how loading files using same method with images, i will edit it, sorry